# Post request only once in nodejs blog app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In my blog application, I'd like a user to comment only once.  Blog app is built with nodejs, mongodb and express. What are some ways to go about it? Not asking for actual code, just ideas on how to implement this.

```
router.post("/",[
check('text').exists().isLength({ min: 2, max:7999 }).trim()
], middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res) {
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.redirect("back");
}

  Car.findById(req.params.id, function(err,car){
      if(err) {
          console.log(err)
          res.redirect("/cars")
      } else {
          Comment.create(req.body, function(err,comment) {
              if(err) {
                req.flash("error", "Something went wrong, please try again.")              
              } else {
                  comment.author.id= req.user._id;
                  comment.author.username = req.user.username;
                  comment.car.id = car._id;
                  comment.car.carname = car.name;
                console.log(comment.author.id== req.user._id, comment._id, "true or false");
                console.log(comment._id)

                  comment.save();
                  car.comments.push(comment);
                  car.save();
                  req.flash("success", "Successfully added review")

                  res.redirect("/cars/"+car._id)
              }
          })
      }
  })
```

});

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
text: String,
```

author: {
        id:
    { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "User" 
    }, 
    username: String
    }

Comment: A small edit to whoever is using this in future. you cannot do const existCom = Comment. Use the normal callback method. and thank u @coockoo for the guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your `comments` table in the database. It includes info about the user and the post user comments on (eg. `comments.user_id`, `comments.post_id`
2. Make `express` handler to accept `POST` request on some endpoint `/comments`. In this body, you expect to receive `post_id`, `user_id` probably via some authentication mechanisms (check out [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) it might help with this one) and some `content`.
3. Make request into the database checking whether the current user has a comment for this post. Example query:

   `db.comments.find({ user_id: req.session.user_id, post_id: req.body.post_id })`
4. If this user has a comment (found in db) – send back status 400 (Bad Request). In case it doesn't exist – create one and send back 200 status code.

Comment: everything works except req.body.post_id is always undefined. :(

Comment: This depends on how you pass your `post_id` to your express application. In case it's body – you need a [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to access a body.

Comment: umm everything is added. this is jst a final  step before making it live. let me add my comment routes and models

Comment: You need something like this. [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne). `const existingCommet = Comment.findOne({ car_id: req.body.car_id, user_id: req.user._id })`. `if (existingComment) { /*already exists*/} else { /*create comment*/ }

Comment: sadly it does not work, however i have got general idea on how to proceed with it. I just had one doubt, why have u used car_id and not simply car.id

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b41ca65490df81a483bca88"
    },
    "text": "#Verna c",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2018-07-08T08:25:09.918Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "author": {
        "id": {
            "$oid": "5ae76f8da57b971e182aa7b6"
        },
        "username": "admin"
    },
    "car": {
        "carname": "Verna",
        "id": {
            "$oid": "5b3ff2e5094a952658a892a5"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Initially, I didn't know your database schema. If I was asked to design the database schema, I'd build it like `comments (id, car_id, author_id, text)`. Kind of the relational approach. So I used it just for you to get the idea of how to approach this question.

Comment: hey man, able to post jst one comment now. thank you for the guidance. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the userid somewhere in collection, maybe push in an array when the user adds a comment.
Before adding comment, check if userid is not present already. If present, reject the comment.
Maybe insert blogID too along with userID if user can comment once on each blog.

Comment: yes this is also a good way to go about it. i already have array of userIds on a post. i should try this too. thanks mate